# Passing variable length parameters into function Swift

Tags: swift

I am reading the iBook apple released with their new language. One of the experiments suggests to write a function to find the average of a set of numbers.

Here is what I have been trying, but getting no feedback from playground.

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}

func calculateAverage(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = sumOf(numbers)
    return sum / numbers.count
}

calculateAverage(33, 44, 66, 132)
```

On the line `var sum = sumOf(numbers)` I get the error:

`Could not find an overload for supplied arguments`

I am having a hard time understanding why I cannot pass the `numbers` parameter of type `Int...` into a method which takes a `Int...`

Does anyone know how I could do something similar to this?

Comment: I think you are parsing an array of numbers and it is expecting a single integer. To test, try replace numbers with a 1 and see if it works like that. var sum = sumOf(10)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, he wants 2 methods with variadic parameters, one  calling the other... not an array parameter...

Comment: You can do this using `var sum = sumOf(reinterpretCast(numbers))`

Answer (score 6):

The `numbers: Int...` parameter in `sumOf` is called a *variadic parameter*. That means you can pass in a variable number of that type of parameter, and everything you pass in is converted to an array of that type for you to use within the function.

Because of that, the `numbers` parameter inside `calculateAverage` is an array, not a group of parameters like `sumOf` is expecting.

You might want to overload `sumOf` to accept either one, like this, so your averaging function can call the appropriate version:

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int[]) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    return sumOf(numbers)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...)
```

to

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int[])
```

You are parsing an Array when it expects a single Int